# Word VBA code on userform to clear inputs into textbox if date is greater than or equal to 11/12/2020 on doc1 and keep displayed on doc2. & vice-versa

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a module:

```vb
Public Doc1 As Document
Public Doc2 As Document
```

And a userform that opens when the document is opened. The userform has a filedialog userpromt where you choose and set doc1 and doc2 like:

```vb
Set Doc1 = Documents.Open(strFile1)
Set Doc2 = Documents.Open(strFile2)
```

After that is set userform2 opens and has a 6x6 table
The Columns are labeled:

```
Name: Program: Amount: Size: Start Date: End Date:
```

Each spot in the table is tied to a bookmark I.e, Program 1, Program 2, -Program 6 and the same with all the other labels.

The table is set up in vba like:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim TextBoxx1 As Range

Set TextBoxx1 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmgn1").Range

TextBoxx1.Text = Me.TextBoxx1.Value

Dim TextBoxx2 As Range

Set TextBoxx2 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmgn2").Range

TextBoxx2.Text = Me.TextBoxx2.Value

Dim TextBoxx3 As Range

Set TextBoxx3 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmgn3").Range

TextBoxx3.Text = Me.TextBoxx3.Value

Dim TextBoxx4 As Range

Set TextBoxx4 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmgn4").Range

TextBoxx4.Text = Me.TextBoxx4.Value

Dim TextBoxx5 As Range

Set TextBoxx5 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmgn5").Range

TextBoxx5.Text = Me.TextBoxx5.Value

Dim TextBoxx6 As Range

Set TextBoxx6 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmgn6").Range

TextBoxx6.Text = Me.TextBoxx6.Value

Dim TextBoxx7 As Range

Set TextBoxx7 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmprogram1").Range

TextBoxx7.Text = Me.TextBoxx7.Value

Dim TextBoxx8 As Range

Set TextBoxx8 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmprogram2").Range

TextBoxx8.Text = Me.TextBoxx8.Value

Dim TextBoxx9 As Range

Set TextBoxx9 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmprogram3").Range

TextBoxx9.Text = Me.TextBoxx9.Value

Dim TextBoxx10 As Range

Set TextBoxx10 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmprogram4").Range

TextBoxx10.Text = Me.TextBoxx10.Value

Dim TextBoxx11 As Range

Set TextBoxx11 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmprogram5").Range

TextBoxx11.Text = Me.TextBoxx11.Value

Dim TextBoxx12 As Range

Set TextBoxx12 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmprogram6").Range

TextBoxx12.Text = Me.TextBoxx12.Value

Dim TextBoxx13 As Range

Set TextBoxx13 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmfgamount1").Range

TextBoxx13.Text = Me.TextBoxx13.Value

Dim TextBoxx14 As Range

Set TextBoxx14 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmfgamount2").Range

TextBoxx14.Text = Me.TextBoxx14.Value

Dim TextBoxx15 As Range

Set TextBoxx15 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmfgamount3").Range

TextBoxx15.Text = Me.TextBoxx15.Value

Dim TextBoxx16 As Range

Set TextBoxx16 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmfgamount4").Range

TextBoxx16.Text = Me.TextBoxx16.Value

Dim TextBoxx17 As Range

Set TextBoxx17 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmfgamount5").Range

TextBoxx17.Text = Me.TextBoxx17.Value

Dim TextBoxx18 As Range

Set TextBoxx18 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmfgamount6").Range

TextBoxx18.Text = Me.TextBoxx18.Value

Dim TextBoxx19 As Range

Set TextBoxx19 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmrfunds1").Range

TextBoxx19.Text = Me.TextBoxx19.Value

Dim TextBoxx20 As Range

Set TextBoxx20 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmrfunds2").Range

TextBoxx20.Text = Me.TextBoxx20.Value

Dim TextBoxx21 As Range

Set TextBoxx21 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmrfunds3").Range

TextBoxx21.Text = Me.TextBoxx21.Value

Dim TextBoxx22 As Range

Set TextBoxx22 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmrfunds4").Range

TextBoxx22.Text = Me.TextBoxx22.Value

Dim TextBoxx23 As Range

Set TextBoxx23 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmrfunds5").Range

TextBoxx23.Text = Me.TextBoxx23.Value

Dim TextBoxx24 As Range

Set TextBoxx24 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmrfunds6").Range

TextBoxx24.Text = Me.TextBoxx24.Value

Dim TextBoxx25 As Range

Set TextBoxx25 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmsdate1").Range

TextBoxx25.Text = Me.TextBoxx25.Value

Dim TextBoxx26 As Range

Set TextBoxx26 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmsdate2").Range

TextBoxx26.Text = Me.TextBoxx26.Value

Dim TextBoxx27 As Range

Set TextBoxx27 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmsdate3").Range

TextBoxx27.Text = Me.TextBoxx27.Value

Dim TextBoxx28 As Range

Set TextBoxx28 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmsdate4").Range

TextBoxx28.Text = Me.TextBoxx28.Value

Dim TextBoxx29 As Range

Set TextBoxx29 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmsdate5").Range

TextBoxx29.Text = Me.TextBoxx29.Value

Dim TextBoxx30 As Range

Set TextBoxx30 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmsdate6").Range

TextBoxx30.Text = Me.TextBoxx30.Value

Dim TextBoxx31 As Range

Set TextBoxx31 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmedate1").Range

TextBoxx31.Text = Me.TextBoxx31.Value

Dim TextBoxx32 As Range

Set TextBoxx32 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmedate2").Range

TextBoxx32.Text = Me.TextBoxx32.Value

Dim TextBoxx33 As Range

Set TextBoxx33 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmedate3").Range

TextBoxx33.Text = Me.TextBoxx33.Value

Dim TextBoxx34 As Range

Set TextBoxx34 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmedate4").Range

TextBoxx34.Text = Me.TextBoxx34.Value

Dim TextBoxx35 As Range

Set TextBoxx35 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmedate5").Range

TextBoxx35.Text = Me.TextBoxx35.Value

Dim TextBoxx36 As Range

Set TextBoxx36 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmedate6").Range

TextBoxx36.Text = Me.TextBoxx36.Value

Set TextBoxx1 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmgn1").Range

TextBoxx1.Text = Me.TextBoxx1.Value

Set TextBoxx2 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmgn2").Range

TextBoxx2.Text = Me.TextBoxx2.Value

Set TextBoxx3 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmgn3").Range

TextBoxx3.Text = Me.TextBoxx3.Value

Set TextBoxx4 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmgn4").Range

TextBoxx4.Text = Me.TextBoxx4.Value

Set TextBoxx5 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmgn5").Range

TextBoxx5.Text = Me.TextBoxx5.Value

Set TextBoxx6 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmgn6").Range

TextBoxx6.Text = Me.TextBoxx6.Value

Set TextBoxx7 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmprogram1").Range

TextBoxx7.Text = Me.TextBoxx7.Value

Set TextBoxx8 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmprogram2").Range

TextBoxx8.Text = Me.TextBoxx8.Value

Set TextBoxx9 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmprogram3").Range

TextBoxx9.Text = Me.TextBoxx9.Value

Set TextBoxx10 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmprogram4").Range

TextBoxx10.Text = Me.TextBoxx10.Value

Set TextBoxx11 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmprogram5").Range

TextBoxx11.Text = Me.TextBoxx11.Value

Set TextBoxx12 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmprogram6").Range

TextBoxx12.Text = Me.TextBoxx12.Value

Set TextBoxx13 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmfgamount1").Range

TextBoxx13.Text = Me.TextBoxx13.Value

Set TextBoxx14 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmfgamount2").Range

TextBoxx14.Text = Me.TextBoxx14.Value

Set TextBoxx15 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmfgamount3").Range

TextBoxx15.Text = Me.TextBoxx15.Value

Set TextBoxx16 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmfgamount4").Range

TextBoxx16.Text = Me.TextBoxx16.Value

Set TextBoxx17 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmfgamount5").Range

TextBoxx17.Text = Me.TextBoxx17.Value

Set TextBoxx18 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmfgamount6").Range

TextBoxx18.Text = Me.TextBoxx18.Value

Set TextBoxx19 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmrfunds1").Range

TextBoxx19.Text = Me.TextBoxx19.Value

Set TextBoxx20 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmrfunds2").Range

TextBoxx20.Text = Me.TextBoxx20.Value

Set TextBoxx21 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmrfunds3").Range

TextBoxx21.Text = Me.TextBoxx21.Value

Set TextBoxx22 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmrfunds4").Range

TextBoxx22.Text = Me.TextBoxx22.Value

Set TextBoxx23 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmrfunds5").Range

TextBoxx23.Text = Me.TextBoxx23.Value

Set TextBoxx24 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmrfunds6").Range

TextBoxx24.Text = Me.TextBoxx24.Value

Set TextBoxx25 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmsdate1").Range

TextBoxx25.Text = Me.TextBoxx25.Value

Set TextBoxx26 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmsdate2").Range

TextBoxx26.Text = Me.TextBoxx26.Value

Set TextBoxx27 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmsdate3").Range

TextBoxx27.Text = Me.TextBoxx27.Value

Set TextBoxx28 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmsdate4").Range

TextBoxx28.Text = Me.TextBoxx28.Value

Set TextBoxx29 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmsdate5").Range

TextBoxx29.Text = Me.TextBoxx29.Value

Set TextBoxx30 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmsdate6").Range

TextBoxx30.Text = Me.TextBoxx30.Value

Set TextBoxx31 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmedate1").Range

TextBoxx31.Text = Me.TextBoxx31.Value

Set TextBoxx32 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmedate2").Range

TextBoxx32.Text = Me.TextBoxx32.Value

Set TextBoxx33 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmedate3").Range

TextBoxx33.Text = Me.TextBoxx33.Value

Set TextBoxx34 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmedate4").Range

TextBoxx34.Text = Me.TextBoxx34.Value

Set TextBoxx35 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmedate5").Range

TextBoxx35.Text = Me.TextBoxx35.Value

Set TextBoxx36 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmedate6").Range

TextBoxx36.Text = Me.TextBoxx36.Value
```

How can I set this up so if the value of any of the start or end dates are greater than or equal to 11/12/2020 it will not input the date and the whole row attached at doc2 and keep the data and corresponding row only doc1. If before the date, it will clear itself in doc1 and the corresponding row its in while inputing into doc2?

Comment: Any excel spreadsheet in this?