# Word VBA- Deleting row that is bookmarked if nothing is entered in textboxx25 - userform

Tags: vba, ms-word, vba7

I have textboxx25 setup so that a user can enter text in it in a userform. For some reason the code below is still deleting the row even if something is entered in the textbox, anyone have any suggestions? The bookmark (bmrow1) is bookmarked to an entire row in a table, textboxx25 is just one cell in the row but textboxx25 is what I'm using to check if its empty or not and if empty delete the row.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

If UserForm3.TextBoxx25.Value = "" Then:

Doc1.Bookmarks("bmrow1").Range.Cells.Delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing simply because it contains two unrelated lines of code. The colon causes the `If` statement to not have an action associated with it, so the bookmarked range gets deleted regardless.

Not sure what you are using the colon for but if you need to continue a line of VBA use an underscore:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

If UserForm3.TextBoxx25.Value = "" Then _
    Doc1.Bookmarks("bmrow1").Range.Cells.Delete
```

Comment: If a User Form textbox is left empty then delete the entire row in a table in a word document (Doc1 and Doc2 are both public in a module and chosen using a file selector).

I have this code below that lets users fill out textboxx25 if it is relevant to a user but it can be left blank. The text box is set up so that if the date is after 11/12/2020 then what is entered into the text box will go onto doc1 and doc2 will be left empty and vice versa if the date is before than. How could I set this up so that if it is left empty it will delete the entire row in the table?

Comment: The table looks like-

All in one Row:

|textbox1|textbox7|textbox13|textbox19|textbox25|textbox31|

Comment: That sounds like a separate question, which I believe you have already [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68534564/word-vba-code-on-userform-to-clear-inputs-into-textbox-if-date-is-greater-than-o). This question has been answered. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: At the risk or repeating myself: This question has been answered. You already have code that deletes an entire row of cells if a textbox is empty - it is the code in the answer above.

Comment: Hey Mr. Rylatt, I have a textbox that is link to a variable. However this textbox can be left blank in the user form and is optional. The issue is that when left blank it pastes "Error! No document variable supplied." into the textbox space. 
The code is and it doesn't currently work:
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

If UserForm3.TextBoxx25.Value = "" or UserForm3.TextBoxx25.Value "Error! No document variable supplied." Then _
    Doc1.Bookmarks("bmrow1").Range.Cells.Delete

Comment: That is a separate question. SO is a question and answer site, ***not*** a forum. Post another question.